# Remove items from or add items to a select box?

Tags: javascript

How to remove items (value="0") from select box?

Below is an example select box.

```
<select class="form-select" name="column" id="edit-column">
<option value="-1">Search All Columns</option>
<option value="0">option 1</option>
<option value="1">option 2</option>
</select>
```

my JavaScript is not working

```
$('#edit-column option[value="0"]').remove();
```

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/RCnTK/

Comment: @PSL - with a replacement of `:` to `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is fine -- you're probably just running it before the DOM is fully loaded.

So, as PSL mentioned in the comments, you have to use something like this in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#edit-column option[value="0"]').remove();
});
```

Which is really just shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-column option[value="0"]').remove();
});
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCnTK/1/).

Comment: Or, if you for some reason wouldn't want to include it in the ready event, make sure that whatever code using it is under the select tag in your file.

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: $ is not a function" 

Below is my js 


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-column option[value="0"]').remove();
});
//--><!]]>
</script>

Comment: Looks like you need to include jQuery in your file then.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>`